# How to group or nest a tree view by a field in Odoo?

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo

I want to create a nested tree view grouping by fields like the following image.

[image]

I did not find any source code within Odoo. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a search view with a `group_by` you can see the lines like that

```xml
<record id="view_account_invoice_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">account.invoice.select</field>
    <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Search Invoice">
            <filter string="Period" context="{'group_by':'period_id'}"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

You must select it in the search view

Comment: Can I embed a nested tree in a notebook->page view ??

Comment: Nope, that's not possible, sorry. You can use a one2many with a domain, but without groups